Filterset_class does not working when view is called from test
I have a drf method view:
    @action(detail=False, methods=["get"], filterset_class=None)
    def count(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

and of course, there is a filterset_class defined on class level. When I called this endpoint from postman, this filterset_class override is working, but when I called it from tests, the override is not working. Im using APIRequestFactory to do the request from test like
factory = APIRequestFactory(email=user.email)
view = NotificationsMessagesView.as_view({"get": "count"})
response = view(request)
result = response.render()
assert result.data["count"] == 1

My versions:
Django = "3.2"
djangorestframework = "3.12.4"
django-filter = "22.1"


Could someone help me? I trying to find maybe so bugreports, but i dont find anything.
I think, the override of filterset_class should be applied when the view is requested from tests.
